# "Unable to encrypt request. Please try again" in flutter app while using flutterwave 1.0.1

Tags: android, flutter, dart, payment-gateway, flutterwave

Payment gateway(Flutterwave)

I am facing this issue while going to pay with test card always showing this error in snackbar in flutter project

```
[1179408211, 1162038111, 1413829460, 1667326818, 1664115256, 842414392, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
I/flutter (15692): #0      FlutterwaveUtils.tripleDESEncrypt (package:flutterwave/utils/flutterwave_utils.dart:15:7)
I/flutter (15692): #1      CardPaymentManager._prepareRequest (package:flutterwave/core/card_payment_manager/card_payment_manager.dart:66:60)
I/flutter (15692): #2      CardPaymentManager.payWithCard (package:flutterwave/core/card_payment_manager/card_payment_manager.dart:85:31)
I/flutter (15692): #3      _CardPaymentState._makeCardPayment (package:flutterwave/widgets/card_payment/card_payment.dart:230:10)
I/flutter (15692): #4      FlutterwaveViewUtils.showConfirmPaymentModal.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutterwave/widgets/flutterwave_view_utils.dart:36:49)
I/flutter (15692): #5      _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:989:21)
I/flutter (15692): #6      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:198:24)
I/flutter (15692): #7      TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:608:11)
I/flutter (15692): #8      BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:296:5)
I/flutter (15692): #9      BaseTapGestureRecognizer.handlePrimaryPointer (
```

i am using latest flutter sdk

flutterwave lib. version
`flutterwave: ^1.0.1`

Answer (score 0):

The package is currently deprecated and hence not supported by flutter.
You could use an alternative pacakage such as (https://github.com/odunboye/flutterwave-flutter.git) recommended by flutter in (https://github.com/Flutterwave/flutterwave-flutter/issues/73).This solved the problem

To use this package, use the command below in your pubspec.yaml

```
flutterwave:
    git:

      url: https://github.com/odunboye/flutterwave-flutter.git
      ref: development
```

then run pub get and you should be fine. Use the documentation on the read.md to guide you further on how to use the package.